# LXC container ubuntu 18.04 apt update problem

Tags: repository, lxc, official-repositories

I use LXC. I have not been able to update for the last 1 week. The errors are as follows: domain name resolution, Ping etc. It works.

```
root@nginx2:~# ping  -c 2  google.com
PING google.com (172.217.18.14) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from fra15s28-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.18.14): icmp_seq=1
ttl=118 time=5.28 ms
64 bytes from fra15s28-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.18.14): icmp_seq=2
ttl=118 time=5.38 ms

# apt install telnet
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  telnet
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 67.1 kB of archives.
After this operation, 165 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 telnet amd64 0.17-41
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/netkit-telnet/telnet_0.17-41_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

root@nginx2:/home/ubuntu# apt update
Ign:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Ign:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Ign:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Err:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
Err:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
Err:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Try a ping to archive.ubuntu.com. I just tried it -- it's up.

Comment: ing archive.ubuntu.com. 
PING archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.88.142) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from aerodent.canonical.com (91.189.88.142): icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=19.1 ms
64 bytes from aerodent.canonical.com (91.189.88.142): icmp_seq=2 ttl=55 time=19.3 ms
64 bytes from aerodent.canonical.com (91.189.88.142): icmp_seq=3 ttl=55 time=19.2 ms

Comment: I too am getting this error.  It's not that 91.189.88.142 is down, it's that the requested URI doesn't exist.